# Using uint for bitwise flags in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to set up 64 boolean flags in a contract.  What's the better option here?

a) bool[64]

b) uint64

And is there way to name each flag in Solidity like:

```
#define BIT_0 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`uint64` should be used for numbers that can be added and multiplied. If you want to perform bit operations, types like `bytes8` should be better suited. A bool array is quite wasteful, as it takes a single byte per element. You can name the flags using constants: `bytes8 constant bit_1 = 2**1;`.

Comment: Could I also name the flags using `uint8` ? @chriseth